# How to remove all characters after the last backslash in a path with Batch

Tags: batch-file, path, virtual-machine

EDIT: The value of `%%a` is

```
<MachineEntry uuid="{awae1979-6512-4br8-acg5-3oe94f56712de}" src="C:\Users\John\VirtualBox VMs\VM\VM.vbox"/>
```

I'm trying to grab the folder of a VMWare Virtual Machine. Since the user can change where the folder is located, the path is never the exact same. I've created a script that grabs the path for any VMs on the system but the issue then is that I have a path that ends in a file. In the code I've provided I tried to use the existing `findstr` loop to remove the slash and trailing characters but it only removes the `C:\`. Here is an example of my current code:

```
(FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "src" VirtualBox.xml') DO (
   SET "line=%%a"
   REM This is the term that the script searches for
   SET "line=!line:*src=!"
   REM This removes the excess characters from the grabbed string
   SET "line=!line:~2,-3!"
   SET "line=!line:*\=!"
   FOR /F "delims=<" %%b in ("!line!") DO ECHO !line!
))
PAUSE
```

In my example code it delivers `Users\John\VirtualBox VMs\VM\VM.vbox`. It ends up only cutting the `C:\` off.  I want it to instead cut the last `\` off giving me `C:\Users\John\VirtualBox VMs\VM`. Any ideas on how I could get the code to iterate from the end of the line instead of from the start? Any advice or suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is using in batch file:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=3 delims=/=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L "src" VirtualBox.xml') do set "VirtualBoxPath=%%~dpI"
echo Virtual box path is: "%VirtualBoxPath%"
```

**FOR** with option `/F` starts in this case a new command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between the two `'` inside the round brackets appended resulting with Windows installed into `C:\Windows` in executing:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /I /L "src" VirtualBox.xml
```

**FINDSTR** searches case-insensitive for lines containing the literal string `src` in file `VirtualBox.xml` in current directory which can be also a directory different to the directory containing the batch file. In this case **FINDSTR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** of background command process the line:

```
<MachineEntry uuid="{awae1979-6512-4br8-acg5-3oe94f56712de}" src="C:\Users\John\VirtualBox VMs\VM\VM.vbox"/>
```

**FOR** captures everything output to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes the captured text line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** ignores always empty lines on processing the captured output.

**FOR** splits up by default each line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as delimiters and assigns just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. The line splitting behavior is modified for this task by specifying `tokens=3 delims=/=` on **FOR** command line after option `/F`.

The string delimiters are now the forward slash `/` and the equal sign `=` which means the XML line to process is split up into:

1. `<MachineEntry uuid`
2. `"{awae1979-6512-4br8-acg5-3oe94f56712de}" src`
3. `"C:\Users\John\VirtualBox VMs\VM\VM.vbox"`
4. `>`

Only the third string is of interest and is assigned to loop variable `I` because of `tokens=3`.
So loop variable `I` gets assigned the string:

```
"C:\Users\John\VirtualBox VMs\VM\VM.vbox"
```

**FOR** ignores by default also all lines starting with a semicolon because of `eol=;` is the default for end of line option. The end of line option must not be changed here because the XML line to process never starts with `;`.

In real **FOR** first splits up the line using the specified or the default string delimiters and then checks if the first substring starts with the specified or default end of line character. So **FOR** would also ignore in this case a line starting for example with `=/;` because of `=` and `/` would be removed during line splitting and then first substring starts with `;` although the line itself starts with `=` and for that reason the line is completely ignored although assigned to loop variable `I` should be the third and not the first substring.

The string assigned to loop variable `I` is referenced with `%%~dp` using three modifiers:

- The first one is `~` which results in removing surrounding `"` from string assigned to loop variable `I`.
- The second one is `d` which means drive letter with colon.
- The third one is `p` which means path without drive letter and colon.
  The path is everything up to last backslash with including the last backslash.

Therefore the string `C:\Users\John\VirtualBox VMs\VM\` is assigned to environment variable `VirtualBoxPath`.

In general it does not matter on applying the modifiers on string assigned to a loop variable if this string really references an existing file or folder. The modifiers are applied on the string itself if no file/folder can be found by **FOR** with the string assigned to referenced loop variable in file system. Of course the file/folder referenced by the string assigned to loop variable must exist if being incomplete like just a file name without file extension is assigned to loop variable and wanted is drive, path or file extension. In this case **FOR** accesses file system to get full qualified file name of incomplete file name string and tries its best to get the wanted data.

Comment: This solution worked the best and most reliably for me, I had to edit the `FOR` loop because I'm dealing with multiple paths but thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Would it not be easier to use the doublequotes as delimiters?

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%A In ('Find "src="^<"VirtualBox.xml"')Do @Echo(%%A
```

or if you only wanted the path, not the full string:

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%A In ('Find "src="^<"VirtualBox.xml"')Do @Echo(%%~dpA
```

**[Edit /]**

Here's an alternative, [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution based upon the location provided by LotPings, in their comment below, and leveraging [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('PowerShell -NoProfile -Command^
 "[XML]$VBoxes = Get-Content "$Env:UserProfile\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml";"
 "$VBoxes.VirtualBox.Global.MachineRegistry.MachineEntry |"
 "ForEach-Object {Split-Path -Path "$_.src" -Resolve}" 2^>Nul'
)Do @Echo(%%A
```

*This is a single line command, changed to multiline to improve readability. In it I have used `Split-Path` along with `-Resolve` so that only results which are currently available are output.*

Comment: Nice one (+1), works with single % on cmd line, using `%USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox` as base dir `@For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %A In ('Find "src="^<"%USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml"') Do @Echo(%~dpA`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `=` and `/` as delimiters to extract the quoted path and then let the [`~` modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) do their job:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=3 delims==/" %%L in ('findstr /I "src=" "VirtualBox.xml"') do (
    echo Full path: %%~L
    echo File name: %%~nxL
    echo Dir. path: %%~dpL
)
```